# Create two DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

please I want to create two DrawerNavigator inside 1 stacknavigator I need the first one will be in Menu Drawer, the second will be for Cart items I need some help or just some ideas how to create this with react-navigation thanks
this my actual implementation

const RootNavigator =
    StackNavigator({

```
    Drawer: {
        screen: DrawerNavigator(
            DrawerRoutesLeft,DrawerContentLeft
        )
    },
        ...AnonymousStack
    },
    { headerMode: 'none' }
);



let drawerStack = {
    Home: {screen: nav_tab},
    Rayon: {title:"Rayon" ,screen: Rayon},
    Product : {screen :Porduct } }


export let DrawerContentLeft = {
    drawerWidth: DEVICE_WIDTH - DEVICE_WIDTH / 5,
    contentOptions: {
        inactiveTintColor: '#333',
        activeTintColor: "#ddd0dd",
    },
    contentComponent: DrawerContent,
    drawerPosition: 'left',

}

let drawerOptions =  {
    navigationOptions:({navigation}) => ({
        headerLeft: <MenuButton navigate={navigation.navigate}/>,
        headerStyle:styles.header
    }) }


export let DrawerRoutesLeft = {
    Home: {
        screen: StackNavigator(drawerStack, drawerOptions)
    },
    Product: {
        screen: StackNavigator(drawerStack)
    } }
```

Comment: You can easily do this with Wix React Native Navigation. Are you forced to use that library?

Comment: yes because i started my project with React Navigation